# Append class from list to URL

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an unordered list. I want to append the class from every element behind the URL. But how can I do that?

Here is my code:

```js
$( "li" ).each(function( index ) {      
  var newClass = $(this).attr('class');         
    console.log(newClass);    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="dropdown-menu-sub AAA ">
    <li class="c76"><a href="url1/">url1</a></li>
    <li class="c77"><a href="url2/">url2</a></li>
    <li class="c78"><a href="url3/">url3</a></li>
</ul>
```

This is what I want:

```
  <ul class="dropdown-menu-sub AAA ">
        <li class="c76"><a href="url1/#c76">url1</a></li>
        <li class="c77"><a href="url2/#c77">url2</a></li>
        <li class="c78"><a href="url3/#c78">url3</a></li>
    </ul>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/onra4cf5/11/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr) function to update the `href` of anchor.

Here In the example I have used overloaded `.attr( attributeName, function)` which set the `href` attribute with value returned by the function.

```js
$(function() {
  $("li a").attr('href', function(_, href) {
    var newClass = $(this).closest('li').attr('class');
    return href +'#'+ newClass;
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="dropdown-menu-sub AAA ">
  <li class="c76"><a href="url1/">url1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="c77"><a href="url2/">url2</a>
  </li>
  <li class="c78"><a href="url3/">url3</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `return href +'#'+ newClass;` if @herrsaidy is strict about the #